# Is there any smoothing controls available in WPF

Tags: wpf, blend

I am using inkcanvas for free hand drawing in my application, once i draw i need to smooth that image, how to achieve that with WPF?any one can guide me?

Comment: "smooth that image", what exactly does that mean?

Comment: I need to reduce noise within an image or to produce a less pixelated image.